# Fiz um projeto usando o template SPA VS2015. Quero tirar a página de login de start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, single-page-application

Fiz um projeto e quando rodo é a página de login que é a primeira a ser mostrada. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para deixar a página Home como principal e não a de login. Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Por acaso você inicia o projeto com a página de login sendo a página atual do Visual Studio? Teste fechar todas as telas do VS e inicie o projeto.

Comment: Por acaso o seu controller/action possui o atributo `[Authorize]`?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui remover. Fiz assim:

No Controller HomeController, removi o atributo `[Authorize]` e na View Index eu Comentei/Removi essas linhas:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
```

Alguém me disse, que essas linhas compiladas chamava, por javascript a página index.

Answer (score 0):

Altere seu `RouteConfig.cs`, ele fica no diretório `App_Start`.

Exemplo:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ele já está assim

Comment: @pnet, então deve ter algum RedirectToAction no index do Home.

Answer (score 0):

Ola,

Ja tentou modificar ou retirar uma tag parecida com essa no webconfig?

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" name=".controlestoque" />
 </authentication>
```

Espero que seja útil!!!

Comment: Anderson, não tem nada parecido com que você postou no meu web.config